# django date_based object_detail issue

Tags: python, django-models

I'm very new to django, trying to create a basic blog as a working learning experience. I'm following a tutorial from WebMonkey but my view does not return any result when I enter a date based url.

Going to `/blog/`, I get the list of all my blog entries.
Going to `/blog/2011/04/24/`, the template spits out the static html but the loop does not produce any result.

My url patterns from `urls.py` are

```
info_dict = {
    'queryset': Entry.objects.filter(status=1),
    'date_field': 'pub_date',
}

urlpatterns = patterns('django.views.generic.date_based',
    (r'(blog/(?P<year>[0-9]{4}))/(?P<month>[a-z]{3})/(?P<day>[0-9]{1,2})/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'object_detail', dict(info_dict, allow_future=True, slug_field='slug',template_name='blog/detail.html')),

    (r'^((blog/(?P<year>[0-9]{4}))/(?P<month>[a-z]{3})/(?P<day>[0-9]{1,2})/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'object_detail', dict(info_dict, allow_future=True, template_name='blog/list.html')),

    (r'^blog/$','archive_index', dict(info_dict, allow_future=True, template_name='blog/list.html')),

)
```

My template `list.html` is

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block pagetitle %}Page Title{% endblock %}
{% block title %}Title: List{% endblock %}
{% block primary %}
    {% for object in latest %}
        <h2>For Debug</h2>
        <h2>{{ object.title }}</h2>
        <p> {{ object.pub_date }} </p>
        {{ object.body_html|truncatewords_html:"20"|safe }}
        <p>tags:{% for tag in object.get_tags%}
                    <a href="/tags/{{tag.name|slugify}}/">{{tag}}</a>
                {% endfor %}
        </p>
        <p>
            <a href="/blog{{object.get_absolute_url}}">more...</a>
        </p>

    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

My Entry model from `models.py`:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    slug = models.SlugField(
        unique_for_date='pub_date',
        help_text='Automatically built from the title.'
    )

    body_html = models.TextField(blank=True)
    body_markdown = models.TextField() 
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Date published')
    tags = TagField()
    enable_comments = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    PUB_STATUS = (
        (0, 'Draft'),
        (1, 'Published'),
    )
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=PUB_STATUS, default=0)
```

I included screenshots of the 2 situations. Why isn't my date based url returning any result?

Full list of blog entries: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtiyR.png
Date specific search :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bc8G0.png

Answer (score 0):

Your date-based URL refers to the `object_detail` view rather than `archive_index`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I changed to archive_index but still no luck :(

(r'^(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[a-z]{3})/(?P<day>[0-9]{1,2})/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'archive_index', dict(info_dict, template_name='blog/list.html')),

I also tried this url pattern to get a year based list but I get the same empty result...
(r'^(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/$','archive_year', dict(info_dict, allow_future=True, template_name='blog/list.html')),
Any idea?